# Java Generic Object Reuse

Tags: java, java-8, type-erasure

I have a class hierarchy, and would like to build a list of attribute setters for each class in the hierarchy.  The code I want to write is similar to the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

class Attribute<E, T> {
    public final Class<T> dataType;
    public final BiConsumer<E, T> setter;
    public Attribute(final Class<T> dataType, final BiConsumer<E, T> setter) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
        this.setter   = setter;
    }
}

class Foo1 {
    public static final List<Attribute<Foo1, ?>> foo1Attrs = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        foo1Attrs.add(new Attribute<>(String.class, Foo1::setProp1));
    }
    public void setProp1(final String prop1) {
    }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo1 {
    // The following line results in an error
    public static final List<Attribute<Foo2, ?>> foo2Attrs = new ArrayList<>(foo1Attrs);
    static {
        foo2Attrs.add(new Attribute<>(Integer.class, Foo2::setProp2));
    }
    public void setProp2(final Integer prop2) {
    }
}
```

When I compile the above, I get the error:

```
error: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayList<>  
public static final List<Attribute<Foo2, ?>> foo2Attrs = new ArrayList<>(foo1Attrs);  
                                                                        ^
  reason: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: Attribute<Foo2,?>
    lower bounds: Attribute<Foo1,?>
where E is a type-variable:
  E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
```

I understand why I am getting the above error.  My question is, what is the typically pattern employed to make the above code compile and run?

The only way I can figure out how to make this work is to create a copy constructor on the `Attribute` class that takes an `Attribute<? extends E, T>`, then duplicate the data members (pointers) stored in the Attribute class into a second memory location with a different type.  This seems really heavy for what should be the equivalent of a static_cast in C++.  The following changes exemplify this approach:

```
class Attribute<E, T> {
    ...
    public final BiConsumer<? super E, T> setter;
    ...
    public Attribute(final Attribute<? super E, T> other) {
        this.dataType = other.dataType;
        this.setter   = other.setter;
    }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo1 {
    public static final List<Attribute<Foo2, ?>> foo2Attrs = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        for (Attribute<Foo1, ?> attr : foo1Attrs)
            foo2Attrs.add(new Attribute<>(attr));
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

To reiterate the question: Is there a better approach to address this compile-time error than that outlined above?

Comment: If you don't mind an unchecked cast warning (or you don't mind suppressing it), `foo2Attrs = new ArrayList<>((List) foo1Attrs)` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `foo2Attrs` can contain an `Attribute<Foo1, ?>` where `Foo1` is a supertype of `Foo2`, it should be declared as type `List<Attribute<? super Foo2, ?>>`. This makes sense because a `Foo2` object can have its attributes set by any attribute setter which targets a superclass of `Foo2`.

Likewise, `foo1Attrs` should be declared as type `List<Attribute<? super Foo1, ?>>`.

This gets rid of the compilation error caused by the first type parameter, but there'll still be a problem when you try to write some code like `foo2Attrs.get(i).setter.accept(foo, 23)`, because the `setter` is inferred as type `BiConsumer<? super Foo2, ?>` and the integer `23` can't be converted to the second `?`.

Comment: The value problem can be solved with a method like `static <E,T> void set(E obj, Attribute<E,T> a, Object value) { a.setter.accept(obj, a.dataType.cast(value)); }` which can be invoked with, e.g. an `Attribute<? super Foo1, ?>`. Of course, there’s no compile-time safety regarding the `Object` parameter, but you can’t have it when treating attributes with different data types uniformly.

Comment: This works for the code in my question, but when I pass a `List<Attribute<? super Foo1, ?>>` to a method that takes an argument of type `List<Attribute<? super Foo2, ?>>`, I get the same compile-time error.  I don't think this can be worked around without creating a copy of the list or using unsafe casts.  If it were, someone would be able to add an `Attribute<Foo2, ?>` to a list that is actually backed by the type `Attribute<? super Foo1, ?>`, resulting in heap corruption.  However, in my case, I know the list is unmodifiable.  Is there a way to extend this answer to a collection of my type?

Comment: Figured it out; I had to change the method signature to take an argument of type `List<? extends Attribute<? super Foo2, ?>>`.  Java generics make my head hurt.

Comment: That's a general problem of using covariant or contravariant types with mutable collections; if you downcast the element type then you have a `List<Foo2>` that you might `get` a `Foo1` from, and if you upcast it then you're allowed to `add` a `Foo1` which you can later `get` from a `List<Foo2>`. Nonetheless, Java lets you do this, and checks the `get` calls at runtime to make sure the object returned matches the class expected there at compile-time. Really, Java's type-system is hobbled by not supporting (and enforcing) covariance or contravariance where the type variable itself is declared.

Comment: You might find it just saves a lot of hassle not to make `Attribute` a generic class. As noted, Java's type system doesn't give you that much additional safety for your efforts in this kind of situation.